# activity is called mutiple times when back navigation from toolbar is pressed

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-navigation

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Interests");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

above is my code - where i am finishing/destroying my activity on calling finish() on back button is pressed.

Comment: try to call onBackpress...

Comment: this happens even when i press back button

Comment: can you post your target activity ?